# Does h2o.splitFrame account for class proportion for multinomial classification?

Tags: h2o

Does h2o.splitFrame account for class proportion for multinomial classification? For example, if my original dataset has three classes with proportion of 20%, 70%, and 10%, when I create train, valid and test datasets, would they have similar class proportion?

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not.

It does the simplest possible random split, handling each row independently with a "coin flip" row-by-row.

The thinking is, since H2O-3 is intended to handle big data, there are enough samples to not worry about it.

Comment: If you wish, nevertheless, to do a stratified sample, you can use the method `stratified_split()` in the Python module. If you wish to do stratified cross validation, you can set the model's parameter `fold_assignment='Stratified'` or construct a k-fold cross-validation column yourself using the Python module's method `stratified_kfold_column()`.